# how can I set and IF inside a table using haml with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am using rails for a project (already started) and for my bad luck they are using haml (my bad luck because I was never good in it).

My problem is that I have my results, and array, and I want to get through it and print some information(thats easy), but now my problem is to make it fit into a table.

The table has 3 columns, the 3 of them with names (so, will be 3 different entries per row), so, I tried to take a counter and do something like this

```
%table{:border => "1"}
conter = 0
@food.each do |f|
  -if conter == 0
    %<tr>
      %<td>
        =f.description
    - conter ++     
  -end
  -if conter == 1
    %<td>
      =f.description
    -conter ++
  -end
  -if conter == 2
    %td
    =f.description
    -counetr = 0
  -end 

end
```

But doesnt work, returns an error of **Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.** which I have no idea how to fix it (to be honest,I still dont know so much about haml, or the "-" sign, when to use it), could anybody give me some help or some explanation of how to implement things in haml?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually every single thing that can be wrong, *is* wrong. Stop being lazy, stop fumbling around, and **read the documentation**, because this seriously isn't that hard:

- Your table body needs to be indented
- Your variable name switches from `conter` to `counter`
- Dashes denote Ruby code: `conter = 0` needs to be `- conter = 0`
- Again, `@food.each` needs to be `- @food.each`
- Tags are just `%tagname`, not `%<tagname>`; `%<td>` needs to be `%td` etc
- You don't `end` blocks in HAML, that's what indentation is for

You also have a serious logic error. Your incrementing `counter` at the end of your first `if`, and then you test it using an `if` instead of an `elsif` for the subsequent checks, so every single branch of your loop will be followed each iteration.

Your code also can't work. When you un-indent your `%tr`, you're *closing that tag*. If you want to nest things within that tag, they need to be *literally nested*.

Comment: thanks! well, the counter and conter I changed it on last minute to paste it here because my variables are wrongly named in spanish (due previous code is too) but thanks for your explanation, was clear